# How to fix "syntax error near unexpected token `done' " in a nested loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that will loop through columns to find an instance of a word.

I decided I do it through nested loops and after executing my code, I get this error:

> ./gallupscript.sh: line 115: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
>   ./gallupscript.sh: line 115:`done'

Here is the area where my code fails:

```
token=2 #token is the column number
starter=0
s1="First" ; s2="Second" ; s3="Third" ; s4="Fourth" ; s5="Fifth"
s=s ; a=1
while [ $token -le 6 ]
do
    cat gallup.csv | cut -d',' -f"$token" | grep -n $strength1 | cut -d':' -f1 > str1
    if [ -s str1 ]
    then
        for i in $(cat str1)
        do
            if [[ $i -ne $number && $starter -eq 0 ]]
            then
                save=$(cat gallup.csv | head -$i | tail +$i | cut -d',' -f1)
                s=s ; s+=$a ; starter=1
                printf "-- $strength1 --"
                printf "${!s} Strength: $save"
            elif [[ $i -ne $number && $starter -ne 0 ]]
            then
                save=$(cat gallup.csv | head -$i | tail +$i | cut -d',' -f1)
                printf ", $save"
            fi
        done
    starter=0
    a=$((a+1))
    token=$((token+1))
    echo #new line
done
```

This code is expected to output the names (in first columns) where the word is matched with the one I am searching for.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will tell you exactly where the bug is: You don't have a `fi` for your `if [ -s str1 ]`.

Comment: BTW, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); when using `printf`, use format strings with placeholders for your variables (`printf '-- %s --' "$strength1"`, or `printf ', %s' "$save"`) to keep those variables' contents from being misinterpreted with format specifiers; and fix the various other quoting issues that http://shellcheck.net/ identifies.

Comment: Oh wow thanks A lot! I can't believe I missed it haha

Comment: ...not really sure why you're using a `str1` file at all, rather than just capturing the pipeline into a variable. Could even capture it straight to an array: `readarray -t items < <(cut -d',' -f"$token" <gallup.csv | grep -n "$strength1" | cut -d':' -f1); for item in "${items[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: thanks for this tip, I will definitely use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your `if` statement, it doesn't have to do with `for`.

Use the following code instead:

```
token=2 #token is the column number
starter=0
s1="First" ; s2="Second" ; s3="Third" ; s4="Fourth" ; s5="Fifth"
s=s ; a=1
while [ $token -le 6 ]
do
    cat gallup.csv | cut -d',' -f"$token" | grep -n $strength1 | cut -d':' -f1 > str1
    if [ -s str1 ]
    then
        for i in $(cat str1)
        do
            if [[ $i -ne $number && $starter -eq 0 ]]
            then
                save=$(cat gallup.csv | head -$i | tail +$i | cut -d',' -f1)
                s=s ; s+=$a ; starter=1
                printf "-- $strength1 --"
                printf "${!s} Strength: $save"
            elif [[ $i -ne $number && $starter -ne 0 ]]
            then
                save=$(cat gallup.csv | head -$i | tail +$i | cut -d',' -f1)
                printf ", $save"
            fi
        done
    fi   #    <------------ add this line
    starter=0
    a=$((a+1))
    token=$((token+1))
    echo #new line
done
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", note the "defined in the help center" link, and #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list behind that link. Questions caused by typos should be closed, not answered -- and by adding an answer, you participate in preventing the OP from being able to delete the question themselves (the other participant being any upvoters).